# How to comment to a photo using facebook c# sdk

Tags: c#, facebook, sdk

I'm success to commented to facebook post using format:

```
fb.Post("owner_id" + "_" + "post_id" + "/comments", message).
```

But using for a facebook photo (example: [this](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=423909524319194))

```
fb.Post("362298920480255_423909524319194/comments",message);
```

I got this error: `#100 : error finding the requested story.`

How can i fix this?

Im using .Net 4.0 and Facebook c# sdk v6.

Comment: just found the solution. Remove owner_id and the undercore.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this, I use it and so far works well.

```
 var commentDicitonay = new Dictionary<string, object>
                                       {
                                           {"id", "your post_id"}, 
                                           {"from", accessToken}, 
                                           {"message", description}
                                       };
    facebookClient.Post("/comments", commentDicitonay);
```

Do you use this permission "user_photos"?